# Does $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n + 1}}$ have a global minimum, for large $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Does the quantity

$$\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n + 1}}$$

have a global minimum, for *large* $n$?

Successive tries at WolframAlpha yield the following results:

[Minimize $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n + 1}}$ for $n > {10}^5$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+%282n%2F%28n+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29+for+n+%3E+%2810%29%5E%285%29)

[Minimize $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n + 1}}$ for $n > {10}^{10}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+%282n%2F%28n+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29+for+n+%3E+%2810%29%5E%2810%29)

[Minimize $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n + 1}}$ for $n > {10}^{15}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+%282n%2F%28n+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29+for+n+%3E+%2810%29%5E%2815%29)

[Minimize $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n + 1}}$ for $n > {10}^{20}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+%282n%2F%28n+%2B+1%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29+for+n+%3E+%2810%29%5E%2820%29)

Looking at the trend, it looks like the *global* minimum value for the quantity

$$\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n + 1}}$$

as $n$ becomes *arbitrarily large* is

$$\sqrt{2} \approx 1.414213562373.$$

Is there a way to prove this assertion without using limits?

Comment: how about polynomial division... ?

Comment: I feel that this is precisely $\liminf$. It will coincide with $\lim$ in this case.

Comment: What does having a global minimum for *large* $n$ mean without involving limits? Furthermore, $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n+1}}$ is an increasing function, so the minimum value on $[b,\infty)$ is just $\sqrt{\frac{2b}{b+1}}$. Did you mean to ask for a global *maximum*?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @J.Loreaux, clarifying if I meant to ask for a global *maximum*.  No, I did intend to ask for a global *minimum*.

Comment: I noticed a typo in the title, let me edit it for the meantime.

Comment: Thanks again for that comment @J.Loreaux, can you write out your comment into an actual answer and include more details, in particular when considering the *minimum* value of $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n+1}}$ on $(b,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request:

Notice that the function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ given by the formula $\frac{2x}{x+1}$ is strictly increasing. For if $x,y\in\mathbb{R}_+$ with $x<y$, then $2x(y+1) = 2xy+2x < 2xy+2y = (x+1)2y$, and therefore, $f(x) = \frac{2x}{x+1} < \frac{2y}{y+1} = f(y)$.

We also note that the function $\sqrt{\cdot{}}:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ is strictly increasing (to prove it note that the derivative is $\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, which is strictly positive on $\mathbb{R}_+$. Furthermore, your function is $g(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2x}{x+1}}=\sqrt{f(x)}=(\sqrt{\cdot}\circ f)(x)$, which is thus a composition of strictly increasing functions and so is itself strictly increasing.

Hence, for all $x\in [b,\infty)$, $b\le x$, so $g(b)\le g(x)$. Therefore, $g$ has a global minimum on $[b,\infty)$, namely $g(b)$. We would like to know what happens as $b\to\infty$. But this just involves taking the limit:

$$ \lim_{b\to\infty} \min_{x\in[b,\infty)} g(x) = \lim_{b\to\infty} g(b) = \lim_{b\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2b}{b+1}} = \sqrt{2}. $$

However, this does ***not*** mean that $\sqrt{2}$ is a global minimum for $g(x)$ on some interval $[b,\infty)$. In fact, $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound on any such interval because $f(x)\le 2$, and so $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}\le\sqrt{2}$. It only means that $\liminf_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \sqrt{2}$.

The upshot of all this is that *as posed*, I don't think your question really makes any sense. I don't mean to cause offense, it is just my honest opinion.

Edit: I forgot to mention: on the interval $(b,\infty)$, $g$ has no minimum value since it is strictly increasing. More precisely, for every $x\in(b,\infty)$, there exists some $y\in(b,\infty)$ with $b<y<x<\infty$ so that $g(y)<g(x)$ since $g$ is strictly increasing. This shows that $g(x)$ is not a minimum value of $g$ on this interval. Furthermore, since $x\in (b,\infty)$ was arbitrary, this shows that $g$ has no minimum value on the interval $(b,\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and comprehensive answer @J.Loreaux!  Gladly accepting your answer now... =)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit confused. Let's use some polynomial division:$$\sqrt{\frac{2n}{n+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{2n+2-2}{n+1}}=\sqrt{2-\frac2{n+1}}$$Clearly as $n\to\infty$, $\dfrac2{n+1}\to0$ and $\sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{n+1}}\to\sqrt2$. This is not an actual *maximum* because our function never actually *equals* $\sqrt2$ -- it's merely an asymptotic upper bound.

Comment: upper bound, no?

Comment: oops! ;-) I was getting confused by OP's terminology

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ is called a "Limit point" @Jose

Comment: Hold on, so $\sqrt{2}$ is actually an *upper bound*?  How about calling it a *limit point*, what does that entail?  How does $\sqrt{2}$ being a *limit point* relate to $\lim \inf$ coinciding with $\lim$?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris it is a limit point because for any band of arbitrarily small width around $\sqrt{2}$ we have the intersection of that band and the function being non-empty.

Comment: Okay, understood.  Thanks @RustynYazdanpour!  =)

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{}$ is an increasing, continuous function. In this case, for "large" arguments $n$, it **at most** becomes non-decreasing. Hence,  "minimum" doesn't really make sense.